# SugarCRM Custom Module: How to Access DetailView in Search

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Let me first explain how it works in the Contacts module. When a search is done, each entry has the "Name" column hyperlinked to the detailView of that "Name."

I have a custom module that I have created. When I do a search I see all the custom fields that I have created and their respective information. However there is no way for me to go to the DetailView window. Unlike the Contacts module, none of my columns are hyperlinks.

I'm new to writing in Sugar. Can someone please advise me on how to do this?

Also, I've been unable to find any good resources for development. I'm well equipped with PHP knowledge but I don't understand the infrastructure of Sugar and I can't find any well written docs anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the field as a link in the `listviewdefs.php` file for you module. Since it is a custom module, the file should be located in this folder `/custom/modules/<my_module>/metadata/listviewdefs.php`. Find the field and insert `'link' => true`, so it looks something like this:

```
$listViewDefs['MyModule'] = array(
'ROW_NUM' => array(
  'width' => '10',  
  'label' => 'LBL_ROW_NUM', 
  'link' => false,
  'default' => true),
'NAME' => array(
  'width' => '25', 
  'label' => 'LBL_QUOTE_NAME', 
  'link' => true,
  'default' => true),
'ACCOUNT_NAME' => array(
  'width' => '20',  
  'label' => 'LBL_ACCOUNT_NAME',
  'id' => 'ACCOUNT_ID',
  'module'  => 'Accounts',        
  'link' => true,
  'default' => true), 
....
```

For documentation you're pretty much on your own, unfortunately. In my experience it is very sparse and scattered, and the official SugarCRM documentation lacks a lot when it comes to the architecture and inner workings of Sugar. Usually a search engine is your best friend when it comes to Sugar.